# Avoiding using globals in python

Tags: python

How can I re-write this program to avoid using my global num1 and num2? I have an extra credit assignment in my programming class to rewrite a couple of programs without using globals, but this one has me stumped...

```
# Define the main function
def main():
    randomNumbers()
    print "Please add the following numbers:"
    print "  ", num1
    print "+ ", num2
    print "------"
    correctAnswer = num1 + num2 
    userAnswer = int(raw_input("   "))
    if userAnswer == correctAnswer:
        print "Great job!"
    else:
        # Return the correct answer for the user
        print "You're wrong! The correct answer was %s!" % correctAnswer 

# Define a function to generate random numbers
def randomNumbers():
    import random # Imports the random module

    # Generates two random numbers to be added
    global num1
    global num2
    num1 = random.randrange(100,1000)
    num2 = random.randrange(100,1000)

# Call the main function
main()
```

**Got it figured out! Thank you so much!**

```
# Define the main function
def main():
    num1, num2 = randomNumbers()
    print "Please add the following numbers:"
    print "  ", num1
    print "+ ", num2
    print "------"
    correctAnswer = num1 + num2 
    userAnswer = int(raw_input("   "))
    if userAnswer == correctAnswer:
        print "Great job!"
    else:
        # Return the correct answer for the user
        print "You're wrong! The correct answer was %s!" % correctAnswer 

# Define a function to generate random numbers
def randomNumbers():
    import random # Imports the random module
    rand1 = random.randrange(100,1000)
    rand2 = random.randrange(100,1000)
    return rand1, rand2

# Call the main function
main()
```

Comment: put the random calls in the main function and forget about the random function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make your `randomNumbers()` function return like this, you can avoid global state.

```
def main():
    # calculate something
    num1, num2 = randomNumbers()
    # calculate something else

def randomNumbers():
    # calculate something
    return num1, num2
```

Combining two values into one value this way is called a "tuple" if you want to look up more information or documentation.

Comment: I guess you get the extra credit for this assignment ;-)

Comment: @recursive I understand that part... But I can't figure out how to print the return values and check them

Comment: @StevenPink: You print and check them exactly the same way you are now.  There is no change at all.

Comment: Thank you! It finally clicked for me :) I haven't used functions with more than one variable before

Answer (score 1):

```
# Define the main function
def main():
    num1 = randomNumbers()
    num2 = randomNumbers()
    print "Please add the following numbers:"
    print "  ", num1
    print "+ ", num2
    print "------"
    correctAnswer = num1 + num2 
    userAnswer = int(raw_input("   "))
    if userAnswer == correctAnswer:
        print "Great job!"
    else:
        # Return the correct answer for the user
        print "You're wrong! The correct answer was %s!" % correctAnswer 

# Define a function to generate random numbers
def randomNumbers():
    import random # Imports the random module

    # Generates two random numbers to be added
    number = random.randrange(100,1000)
    return number


# Call the main function
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    num1 = random.randrange(100,1000)
    num2 = random.randrange(100,1000)
    print "Please add the following numbers:"
    print "  ", num1
    print "+ ", num2
    print "------"
    correctAnswer = num1 + num2 
    userAnswer = int(raw_input("   "))
    if userAnswer == correctAnswer:
        print "Great job!"
    else:
        # Return the correct answer for the user
        print "You're wrong! The correct answer was %s!" % correctAnswer
```

Try that?

Comment: That would work, but we're supposed to use functions for computations like that when possible.